# Can you use a POST to GET data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, url

A company is asking me to do an `Angular` assignment. They provide the following instructions, but the API URL doesn't work:

```
Create a single page angular application and use the following API to retrieve sports results and sort into a table of results that are displayed. Each sport result contains several data and always includes the publication time. 
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Url: https://ancient-wood-1161.getsandbox.com:443/results 
Tasks:
-Display the sports results in reverse chronological order on the page.
-Add a filter to the page to display only certain types or events (e.g. f1Results)
-How can you confirm the code works?
-Bonus: Implement the rest call asynchronously
```

You can click the URL https://ancient-wood-1161.getsandbox.com:443/results right now and see that it doesn't work - it returns `{"errors":[{"message":"Error processing request"}]}` and in Angular it gives me a standard CORS error.

I asked the company to please send a working URL and/or update the API to accept requests from everywhere. Their response was:
`*guy's name* confirmed it worked. It is a post and the content type is json.`

Can you use a `POST` request to `GET` data?

Comment: I guess on a lower level than what we're initially taught (Being 'GET' is for GET, POST to create, PUT to update, DELETE to delete etc) it's all the same to the HTTP protocol. You can use POST to do anything a GET can do and you can use GET to do anything a POST can do. (Yes, you can even send form data or JSON in a GET body)

This just doesn't follow the "typical standard" if a body isn't required. It's absolutely fine to do and won't cause any issues.

Comment: It's a truly crappy API definition but use something like Postman or Insomnia and POST to the URL with a URL parameter - i.e. https://ancient-wood-1161.getsandbox.com/results?blah=blech and then decide if you really want to work for them :)

Comment: @ConorReid - from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) - "Note: Sending body/payload in a GET request may cause some existing implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined. It is better to just avoid sending payloads in GET requests."

Comment: @stdunbar Of course I would never use or recommend it in practice, I wanted to emphasise the idea that HTTP isn't as strict as its method, content or response and there are alternative ways requests can be made outside of the standard to achieve the same results.

Comment: In some environments @ConorReid it is an error to try to access the body of a GET.  JavaEE, for example, will always return null for the body.  It is not "absolutely fine".

Comment: Whether JavaEE or any environment for that matter restricts what you're able to do that does not affect what HTTP allows you to do. JavaEE isn't returning null because that's the correct answer, JavaEE is returning null because programmatically that's what it's configured to do, JavaEE isn't HTTP and doesn't control what HTTP allows. JavaEE is just trying to make it easier for users who don't have a deep understanding of HTTP running into easy bugs (accidentally using GET instead of POST etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Take for example your avg Login Request that returns an access token for instance. It is going to be a POST as POST also has a bit more security than GET given that the payload is in the body rather than the URL string.

As for their excuse of it not working, try it in postman and see if the same issue still occurs. If it still does then ask them where did they test their API as if it is on prem then no duh the CORS would work. It is most likely not a company you would want to work for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. On some cases it may be necessary, since GET doesn't take a body while POST does. So it can get you around things like URL length limits.